# Is there a name for these kind of website template or can you suggest some free/open-source website template similar to this?

Tags: gratis, open-source

I am developing a static website for which I would like to include a default template something like this: https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/global-logistics-solutions-isometric-landing-page_10385759.htm?query=supply%20chain%20management

I am looking for a template similar to this or some template where we have a vertical navigation bar with various pages and links to them on the right side vertical navigation bar.

1. Do we have a specific name for these types of navigation bars?
2. Can we get some similar templates for free or open-source from somewhere?

Can someone please suggest some free template similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

These are colloquially known as "bootstrap" websites. There are plenty of templates around if you search for something like "HTML5 bootstrap template"